# My application cannot run on android 11 down

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sdk, androidx

I have application but just can run on android 11,12,13 and can't run on android 10,9,8,7. If i build it and open the application on android 10,9,8,7 that will force close. I have set minSdk to 24 and targetSdk to 33 but still can't run on android 10,9,8,7. What's wrong?
Maybe you can help me to resolve this.

[minimum target sdk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxBEC.png)

Comment: "If i build it and open the application on android 10,9,8,7 that will force close" -- use Logcat to examine the stack trace associated with your crash: https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-debug-001.html

Comment: You might be using some api which requires a minimum sdk of 30. Check your code for an annotation @RequiresApi or use the Logcat to see the exact crash log.